# How to create a database from individual scripts?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, deployment, tfs

A project I am working on is storing each database object (tables, store procedures, etc) in its own file in source control, TFS.  I am thinking about implementing a workflow that will build the database in a Windows Azure SQL Server VM instance tied to TFS commits that will run tests for continuous integration.

How does one reconstruct the database from these individual files?  Since there are dependencies to consider among other things, is there a standard practice on how to construct a database with needed structure when the objects are stored in individual files?

I am thinking that file by file might not actually be a realistic way to do this?  If this is the case, do some companies keep an empty database in the testing domain to be filled with data for CI purposes and not drop the database during test tear down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your team had a SQL Server Database Project at some point. If it's not there, you can create one, and include the individual script files in the appropriate folder in the SQL Server Database Project.

Then all you have to do is right click and deploy to whichever environment you want to deploy the database to.

Here's more: [CREATING A SQL SERVER DATABASE PROJECT IN VISUAL STUDIO 2012.](http://candordeveloper.com/2013/01/08/creating-a-sql-server-database-project-in-visual-studio-2012/)